# How to find a value of one vector, in a range of value in another vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, find

I have a vector A with size of 54000 x 1 and vector B with size of 54000 x 1 which is standard deviation of elements of A. From the other side, I have vector C with size of 300000 x 1. Now I want to find that each element of vector C correspondences to which row of vector A with accepted range 3*standard deviation? I have written the below code and it works fine for small vector but for large vector such that I have it is too too slow!!

```
    for i=1:length(A)
      L=A(i,1)- 3*B(i,1);
      U=A(i,1)+ 3*B(i,1);
      inds{i,1} = not(abs(sign(sign(L - C) + sign(U - C))));
     end
```

Does anybody know how can I make this code faster or does anybody know another solution? THX.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is an acronym for Matrix Laboratory and was developed to simply and speed up matrix(vector) calculations. Compared to C or any other programming language you can often skip the for loops when working with matrices. For your code you should be able to skip the for loop and do it as this:

```
  L = A - 3*STD;
  U = A + 3*STD;
  inds = not(abs(sign(sign(L - C) + sign(U - C))));
```

And remember that `i` means the complex number in Matlab. Don't know if it affects speed though.

Edit:

Getting the result as a cell:

```
inds = num2cell(inds)
```

Comment: The inds matrix should be the cell array. since I want to compare all element of vector M with all elements of vector A and see that each element of vector M can be placed in which rows of vector A with the accepted range. So your solution didn't solve the problem but thx for your answer

Comment: When I used your code then I receive this error :
Matrix dimensions must agree.